# scala about trait constructor order

Tags: scala

I have a question about trait constructor order.

```
class Account(initialBalance: Double) extends ConsoleLogger {
  private var balance = initialBalance

  def withdraw(amount: Double) = {
    if (amount > balance) log("Insufficient funds")
    else {
      balance -= amount;
      balance
    }
  }

  def getAccount = balance
}

trait Logged {
  def log(msg: String): Unit = {}
}

trait ConsoleLogger extends Logged {
  override def log(msg: String): Unit = {
    println(msg)
  }
}

trait TimestampLogger extends Logged {
  override def log(msg: String) {
    super.log(new Date() + " " + msg)
  }
}

trait ShortLogger extends Logged {
  val maxLength = 15

  override def log(msg: String) {
    super.log(if (msg.length <= maxLength) msg else msg.substring(0, maxLength - 3) + "...")
  }
}

object test9 extends App {
  val acct1 = new Account(100) with ConsoleLogger with TimestampLogger with ShortLogger
  val acct2 = new Account(100) with ConsoleLogger with ShortLogger with TimestampLogger

  acct1.withdraw(500)
  acct2.withdraw(500)
}
```

the result is :

```
> Sun Sep 20 21:25:57 CST 2015 Insufficient... 
> Sun Sep 20 2...
```

In acct1, the first is ShortLogger.log, the second is TimestampLogger.log. 
In acct2, the first is TimestampLogger.log, the second is ShortLogger.log.

But as I know, trait constructor order is from left to right.

So acct1's trait constructor order is:

```
Logged, ConsoleLogger, TimestampLogger, ShortLogger.
```

Why is ShortLogger.log executed first?

Comment: This is down to linearisation rules: https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html. In my opinion, they are the most insane part of Scala along with implicit resolution rules. Once you have worked out the linearisation of your hierarchy then "When any of these classes and traits invokes a method via super, the implementation invoked will be the first implementation to its right in the linearization."

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's all about [linearization](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.ca/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html).

> Definition 5.1.2 Let C be a class with template C1 with ... with Cn { stats }. The linearization of C, L(C) is defined as follows: L(C) = C , L(Cn)+: ... +: L(C1)
>
> Here +: denotes concatenation where elements of the right operand replace identical elements of the left operand.

You can check this question, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511722/stackable-traits-pattern-methods-implementation-needs-abstract-override-mo) is very clear. Basically, the idea is that in order to figure out which method is called first, you must linearize your class. So with the first example :

```
new Account(100) with ConsoleLogger with TimestampLogger with ShortLogger

L(Account) = Account + L(ShortLogger) + L(TimestamLogger) + L(ConsoleLogger)
L(Account) = Account + ShortLogger + Logged + TimestamLogger + Logged + ConsoleLogger + Logged
```

Linearization requires to remove all duplicates except the last one :

```
L(Account) = Account + ShortLogger + TimestamLogger + ConsoleLogger + Logged
```

So in this example, the first call to log will trigger the one defined in ShortLogger, then TimestamLogger, and so on. With the second example :

```
new Account(100) with ConsoleLogger with ShortLogger with TimestampLogger

L(Account) = Account + L(TimestampLogger) + L(ShortLogger) + L(ConsoleLogger)
L(Account) = Account + TimestampLogger + Logged + ShortLogger + Logged + ConsoleLogger + Logged
L(Account) = Account + TimestampLogger + ShortLogger + ConsoleLogger + Logged
```

Here, the first method called is the one from TimestampLogger, then ShortLogger, and ConsoleLogger. Is this answering your question ?

Answer (score 1):

It's related to [Linerization](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.fi/2009/08/scala-class-linearization.html)

```
object Main extends App {
  val acct1 = new SavingsAccount with ShortLogger
  val acct2 = new SavingsAccount with TimeStampLogger


  val acct3 = new SavingsAccount with TimeStampLogger with ShortLogger
  val acct4 = new SavingsAccount with ShortLogger with TimeStampLogger

  acct1.withdraw(100)
  acct2.withdraw(100)

  acct3.withdraw(100)

}
```

To understand the behaviour I have created **acct1** and **acc2**:

```
acct1.withdraw(100) // => Insufficient...

acct2.withdraw(100) // => Wed Apr 05 11:59:09 EEST 2017 Insufficient amount

acct3.withdraw(100) // => Wed Apr 05 11:59:09 EEST 2017 Insufficient...
```

The behaviour of **acct3**: /* `+:` denotes concatenation */

```
acct3 = acct1 +: acct2
```

Note: **Duplicates** in **acct2** is **removed** when **acct1** is applied

under the hood:

```
L(Account) = Account + L(ShortLogger) + L(TimestamLogger) + L(ConsoleLogger)
L(Account) = Account + ShortLogger + Logged + TimestamLogger + Logged + ConsoleLogger + Logged
```

Same method could be applied for **acct4**